# Javascript animation fade out before video end

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I am attempting to play a video then have the div fade out to 0 opacity at sixty seconds before completion. The issue I'm having is that in removing of the animation on the div which allows the video to fade in at the beginning in effect switches off the div, (the video). What I want to achieve is a fadeout at 60 seconds. What I hope to achieve is remove id animation without affecting video playback, then add timecode which will fade out video / (div) 60 seconds before the end. I may not have not explained this very well see the JSfiddle.

```
var callOnce = true;

function aperture(){
        if ((media.duration - media.currentTime) < 60)
        if (callOnce) {
          sync();
          callOnce = false;
        }
}

function sync(){
        "use strict";
        var media = document.getElementById("media");
        media.classList.add("timecode");
        media.classList.remove("animation");
}
setInterval(aperture, 100);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oytqq0jb/

Comment: Instead of using `callOnce` I suggest using `clearInterval()` to stop the timer and `aperture` won't run anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Your time detection code is correct, but the way you're handling the animation is wrong. Here I show what `sync()` and its CSS animation should look like:

```js
function sync () {
  var video = document.querySelector('.video');
  video.classList.add('anim-fade-out');
}
setTimeout(sync, 2000);
```

```css
.video {
  width: 160px;
  height: 90px;
  background: black;
}

@keyframes fade-out {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.anim-fade-out {
  animation: fade-out 1s forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="video"></div>
```

Add the animation only when you want to start the fade out, there's no need to mess with `running`/`paused`. Once you add the class, the `forward` keyword will keep the last state of the animation when it's done animating, which in this case is `opacity: 0`