# Javascript fade function on end of video

Tags: javascript

I attempting to impliment a one time fade in to the following function but am struggling on how to combine the two without errors. Any help appreciated!

```
var callOnce = true;

function aperture() {
    if ((media.duration - media.currentTime) < 90)
        if (callOnce) {
            sync();
            callOnce = false;
        }
}

function sync() {
    "use strict";
    // Fade function here
}

setInterval(aperture, 100);
```

The fade function:

```
var s = document.getElementById('media').style;
s.opacity = 1;
(function fade() {
    (s.opacity -= .1) < 0.1 ? s.opacity = 0 : setTimeout(fade, 40)
})();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript animation fade out before video end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38095226/javascript-animation-fade-out-before-video-end)